# Increase the speed that a file is downloaded

Tags: python, python-requests

I have profiled the code sorted the stats by `tottime`. Here is where most of the time is spent:

1. `\xlrd\xlsx.py:620(do_row)`
2. `{method 'feed' of 'xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser' objects}`
3. `xlrd\xlsx.py:540(own_process_stream)`
4. `{method 'read' of '_ssl._SSLSocket' bjects}`
5. `xml\etree\ElementTree.py:1286(read_events)`
6. `xlrd\sheet.py:691(put_cell_unragged)`
7. `pandas\io\excel.py:491(_parse_excel)`

I'm trying to optimize a library I created [bls-datasets](https://pypi.org/project/bls-datasets/). It downloads excel files and turns them into dataframes. Some of the files are very large (>50mb) and take some time to download. Just to reiterate, the download is successful, it just takes a good amount of time for the larger files.

I was curious if there were any other options that can increase the speed that of this download, or if it is out of my control.

Currently, I'm using a `requests.get()`to get a ziparchive, turning that into a zipfile object and then opening the designated file of the zipfile.

Comment: Is the library the "bottleneck", or the network connection?

Comment: If you are just creating dataframes, you can probably just convert your excel files into csv files.  These should be much smaller.

Comment: `request` doesn't do anything funky, I don't believe.  I've used it a time or two and it does things without issue.  If I had to suspect, it's just a slow download.

Comment: When you want to improve the performance of an application, you should start by profiling it. It will show you where your bottleneck is. Once you have it narrowed down to a small segment of code, try posting it here, and it may be easier to answer. We can't speculate meaningfully about why or why not this will be faster without a [MCVE]

Comment: @Ares, thanks for the tip. I tried profiling and the results were very long and hard to understand. I will try to better understand the results and follow up.